# Share On Twitter Button Code Question - Which is the best?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I feel like this should be an easy question but I can't seem to find the answer. I just added a Share on Facebook button on a web page that I am working on. Works great. Simply pasted the javascript. I am looking for a button that will allow the user to "share this page" on twitter. I can find one for "follow me on twitter" but not where it will pop something up that says "currently reading" etc. Anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to do anchor such as:

```
http://twitter.com/status/update?status=TESTTESTTES
```

But the main minus of this method, what user must to click "send" button on twitter.

Comment: Hmm. Nowadays this method require POST.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [tweetmeme](http://tweetmeme.com/) or [topsy](http://topsy.com/) button